# Battlefield 3 explosion "deaf" effect?

Tags: effect

When an explosion happens near you in Battlefield 3, your sounds change into low "deaf" versions of themselves, as if you hear only vibrations and not the sounds. Amazing effect. How to add it to a sound? Particularly I am interested in how to do it in Unity, but any terminology/advise/link would be welcome as I am quite new to sound design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary deaf effects are done with a low pass filter on the sound, then a single high pitched sine wave to emulate the ringing. I am not sure how unity works, but when the player if deaf, use their dsp api to low pass filter all the game sounds, and then play an additional sine wave sound.

[unity low pass](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioLowPassFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and check if it answers my question.

Comment: Turns out it's the perfect answer, thanks! I need to make sure my sounds aren't clipping though)

Comment: I feel like the actual low pass introduces some weird noice, is there a common reason for this? At first I thought my source sounds are too loud but this noice happens in different areas, do you have any ideas why is that happening? And one more thing, I noticed that sounds start playing quite inconsistently after the low pass - some get really quiet, is there any way to fix that with a filter?

Comment: I turned the cutoff freq down to almost zero and realized that the noice I talked about is actually clicks. Do i need some form of "remove clicks" filter for that?

Comment: If the sounds you are fitering have no frequencies below the cutoff point, they will become very quiet. Eg a bird chirping would become almost silent, because removing the high frequencies removes the entire sound. There should be no clicks, if there is the filter maybe be misused in some way....but I am not familiar with Unity's low pass filter.